# Variable to provide iteration number for Hive Query reading from Kinesis stream in an AWS Datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, hiveql, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create an AWS Datapipeline that excutes a Hive Query whose output is written to an S3 Bucket. The data is then moved from the S3 bucket in an AWS Redshift Cluster.

The Hive Query is using a Kinesis Stream as its input. I'm trying to leverage Kinesis' checkpointing capability and want to pass a variable to my ShellCommandActivity so I can set the iteration number in the hive script. Is there anyway for me to have a variable that increments by 1 every time the datapipeline is run?

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: Maybe you want to create a tiny DynamoDB table with a counter and use the AWS SDK to read and increment the value.

Comment: @user2654093, did you ever figure this out?  Thought about the dynamo table as well but was hoping for a better way.

Comment: @GregSchnieNeiheisel, I did actually come up with a slightly frustrating way to do it, but it works like a charm. I ended up using an additional ShellCommandActivity. You can using Staging Directories that allows the Shell Script to work directly on a file saved in S3.

The final solution was a new activity that waited for the checkpoint to finish being processed that just goes in and updates the checkpoint number in the ShellScript.

Forgive me if I'm not explaining this well. Ping me with anymore questions. More than willing to help!

http://goo.gl/SHmGC7  - AWS doc for ShellCommandActivity.

Comment: @user2654093 can you provide please sample ? I try to build one same way to avoid dynamoDB.